# Проблемы с подключенным шрифтом

Tags: html, css

При подключении шрифта из google fonts, начинают смещаться соседние элементы от элементов с установленным шрифтом. Что за косяки? первую проблему решил вертикальным выравниванием, а вторую фиксированной высотой в 40px. Вот именно для второй проблемы, подходит фиксированная высота или лучше по-другому решить? так как в макете установлены размер и межстрочный интервал в 40px.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
html,
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background: #f3f3f3;
}

.title {
 /* height: 40px;*/
 margin: 20px 0;
 background: #6a8da2;
}

.title h1 {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0;
 margin-left: 20px;
 padding: 0 10px;
 font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
 font-size: 40px;
 line-height: 40px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #676767;
 background: #f3f3f3;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="title">
   <h1>About us</h1>
  </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте `vertical-align: top;` к заголовку, должно помочь.

```css
html,
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background: #f3f3f3;
}

.title {
 /* height: 40px;*/
 margin: 20px 0;
 background: #6a8da2;
}

.title h1 {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0;
 margin-left: 20px;
 padding: 0 10px;
 font-size: 40px;
 line-height: 40px;
 font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #676767;
 background: #f3f3f3;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="title">
   <h1>About us</h1>
  </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: А из-за чего так происходит , что элементы смещаются?

Comment: Полагаю, дело в том, что [baseline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseline_(typography)) у шрифта «Oswald» отличается от обычного `sans-serif`, а так как стандартное значение `vertical-align` — `baseline`, блок выводится со смещением по вертикали. На всякий случай, `vertical-align: bottom` сработал бы не хуже, лишь бы не `baseline`.